# How to know from which url user send curl request

Tags: php, mysql, curl, laravel-5

Can you tell me how to know from which server/site I get curl request?

The story is something like that: I have API for some data. Users can get that data using query with API key. But in server (API) side I must detect is that valid key for user who send curl request to my API. How to do that? Did I need some more variables like secret key or something and how to do that?

API is in Laravel5 and use MySQL database.

Maybe it helps, I call curl on this way:

```
$query['appkey'] = 'some lenght key';
$str = '';
foreach($query as $k => $v)
    $str .= $k.'='.$v.'&';
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "http://apiwebsite/api/data?" . $str;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I would think the API key is unique and used to identify your user so I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: Yea it's unique but user can use that key in many sites, so I want disable it option.

Comment: curl is irrelevant here. it's just an HTTP request.

Comment: can you show me an example how to make that request? I use it Controller (backend).

Comment: I make correction on my request. I find "josh-hornby/http" package to make request but I still have a problem: How to know from which server comes to my API request. I need to know that to make user use only one key for one site, not for many sites use one API key.